# Angular 6 using 'h' as time separator

Tags: angular, date, date-pipe

Is there any built-in easy way to use 'h' as hours/minutes separator? I am trying to do something like this "12h45" as per:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_France

For other countries it is quite easy e.g.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateFormat'
})
export class DateFormatPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    switch (args) {
      case 'en': {
        return super.transform(value, 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a');
      }

      case 'fr': {
        return super.transform(value, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'); // <--- find proper separator
      }

      case 'de': {
        return super.transform(value, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
      }

      case 'es': {
        return super.transform(value, 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:MM');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: selected date formats might not be true or in everyday use, this is just for demo purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no built-in solution to use 'h' as separator. Although, as you can see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.6/packages/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts#L12-L178), the `transform()` methods always return either `string` or `null`. You can leverage on this and use the `.replace()` method to substitute the semicolon with the h letter:

```
case 'fr': {
    const transformedDate = super.transform(value, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    return transformedDate?.replace(':', 'h');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me: return transformedDate.replace(':', 'h');

Comment: That was the answer before I edited it. Actually, using the OR operator is a safer solution. If DatePipe can't parse the date it will return null, and if you call `replace()` on something that's not a string, you'll receive the famous `Cannot read property 'replace' of null`

Comment: Yes, but if I us it with OR then it doesn't replace, without it it works.

Comment: Ops, my mistake (I'm sleepy!). I meant AND

Answer (score 3):

You can also do either of these two:

```
super.transform(value, 'H\'h\'mm');
super.transform(value, "H\'h\'mm");
```

Anything in the format string that is enclosed in single quotes is shown as is. So if `value` has time as 1:15pm, this will return `13h15`.

See it work on this fiddle: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvtdpw